# Missing textures in Naval Strike maps

Tags: technical-issues, battlefield-4

I did a clean install of my pc, installed origin and then Battlefield 4. After starting BF4 it kept prompting me to install the expansion packs. When I clicked the link it would bring up origin and do nothing. After a few tries the waiting icon appeared but still nothing happend. Sometimes it started updating but then it would tell me that the update failed after a few seconds.

For some reason it just started working out of the blue after trying and rebooting a bunch of times. I was playing with no problems whatsover until I ran into a Naval Strike map. The bottom half of the deploy screen is all fuzzy and when I launch it looks like this [image: game] It takes somewhere between a few seconds and a minute for the game to crash after that.

I already tried to repair the game via origin but I want to put off reinstalling for a long as possible because of my internet connection.

I hope somebody knows what's wrong.

BTW the Xpack1-3 were all set to true by the game.

Some more screenshots, this is after a new launch of battlefield GPU temp 50C. When I deploy it crashes instantaneously. 
[image: Imgur]

PC specs:

I7 3770k @ 4.0 GHz WC'ed
GTX 770
SDD RAID 0 and 16 RAM.

Comment: That doesn't look like missing textures so much as artifacting going on.  Your video card may be overheating.

Comment: @Frank My GPU doesn't go over 79 degrees celsius and it only at 50% fan. That shouldn't be a problem. And it only happens in the Naval Strike maps and right from the start.

Comment: Have you tried doing a repair on the game?  Open origin, and right click on the game.  Select Repair game and let that process.   Are you overclocking your video card at all?

Comment: @ZeroStack I have tried to repair the game but with no succes. The videocard is factory overclocked, I'm pretty sure it's not an issue with my GPU.

Comment: That's hard to believe, as your screenshots are a perfect fit for video artifacting.  Your card may run at optimal temperatures now, but it may have been damaged in the past.  You say it only happens on Naval Strike maps, though?  Can you try some other graphic-intensive games and see what they do?  That would help isolate what's going on.

Comment: 79 degrees celsius seems hot to me, my card doesn't go above 60 when playing. This looks to me to be card issues more than anything.

Comment: Try running some graphics card benchmarking tools. Valley benchmark is free as is FurMark, also CatZilla and 3D Mark. Be carefull with FurMark as it will PUNISH your card hard.